# Whats the use of std::cin >> setprecision(n)?

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) says:

> When used in an expression `out << setprecision(n)` or `in >> setprecision(n)`, sets the precision parameter of the stream `out` or `in` to exactly `n`.

The example on the bottom of the same page demonstrates the use with `std::cout`.

Also for inputstreams the page explains that `str >> setprecision(n)` is effectively the same as calling a funciton that calls `str.precision(n)`. But what for? What is the effect of `std::cin >> setprecision(n)` ?

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double d;
    std::cin >> std::setprecision(1) >> d;
    std::cout << d << "\n";
    std::cin >> std::fixed >> std::setprecision(2) >> d;    
    std::cout << d << "\n";
}
```

With this input:

```
3.12
5.1234
```

Produces [this output](https://godbolt.org/z/vKfv1rGsM):

```
3.12
5.1234
```

So it looks like it has no effect at all. And reading about [`std::ios_base::precision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) it also seems like precision only makes sense for out streams:

> Manages the precision (i.e. how many digits are generated) of floating point output performed by `std::num_put::do_put`.

What is the reason `std::setprecision` can be passed to `std::istream::operator>>`, when, according to cppreference, it effectively calls `str.precision(n)` which only affects output?

Comment: Probably easier to let the code compile for this one case than to try and fix it such that the `std::setprecision` stream modifier was an exception.

Comment: @RichardCritten this was one of my first ideas, but only on a second thought I actually understand it ;). iomanips are just functions and there is only one `>>` overload for all manips....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `setprecision` with either `<<` on a `std::basic_ostream` or `>>` on a `std::basic_istream` has the exact same effect, affecting only how output on the stream will be handled. The precision attribute is stored in the virtual `std::ios_base` base class, which is unified among input and output streams, which is why it still can work on an input stream.

But on a pure input stream I don't see any application for it. On a bidirectional stream however, this allows using both `<<` or `>>` to set the output precision.

Whether there is a specific benefit to allowing `setprecision` with `>>` isn't clear to me. This originally wasn't in the first C++ standard draft, but was added with a CD ballot comment to C++98, see comment CD2-27-015 in [N1064](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1997/N1064R1.pdf). Unfortunately the comment doesn't give a rationale.